# New objects always merged with existing ones

Tags: modifiers, collections

[image]In Short I have an Object already created. Now i want to add a new cube to make an array with it. but it is always on the same "layer" as the existing one. If i make array it makes copies of both. I cant seem to get the object into a new collection. Blender doesnt create a new object in the collection named: "cube". It seems to add it to an existing cube somehow. How can i make it seperate i am loosing my mind... Thanks for any help

as seen in pic stairs and left buidling are somehow one. Why? I made multiple new cubes but as you can see in top right there are only 2 cube layers.

Comment: Most likely the new cube was added in edit mode instead of object mode. Use tab to switch between object mode and edit mode.

Comment: Thank you!! That seems to be the problem. Ty so much for the quick answer!